# Can not get PACK with PWD_AUTH command of NTAG213 using PN532

Tags: authentication, arduino, nfc, rfid, mifare

---Update on 2014/10/03------------
Thanks for Michael Roland's advice.

I tried to see the "real" response from PN532.
I changed my code like this, so I can read the response:

```
uint16_t PN532::mifareultralight_IntoAuth (uint8_t *Password, uint8_t *PACK)
{
    /* Prepare the command */
    pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_COMMAND_INDATAEXCHANGE;
    pn532_packetbuffer[1] = 1;                   /* Card number */
    pn532_packetbuffer[2] = MIFARE_U_CMD_PWD_AUTH;     /* Xsys MH: Mifare Ultralight Read command = 0x1B */
    memcpy (pn532_packetbuffer + 3, Password, 4);        /* Password Payload 

    /* Send the command */
    if (HAL(writeCommand)(pn532_packetbuffer, 7)) {
        return 0xAA;
    }
    /* Read the response packet */
    int16_t status = HAL(readResponse)(pn532_packetbuffer, sizeof(pn532_packetbuffer));
    return status;
}
```

I am using the default Key:
    uint8_t Password[4] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };

I got the response 0xFFFC
Now I get confused, the deafault PACK is 0x0000, so it is not a PACK, if it is a NACK, why did I got a NACK with 2 byte?

Did I do it right?

Any advice is thanksful!!

----Post on 2014/09/22-------------

I am trying to access the authenticated state of a Ntag213 with pn532.
Here is the code, how I was doing that:

Sub-function of the accessing:

```
uint8_t PN532::mifareultralight_IntoAuth (uint8_t *Password, uint8_t *Response)
{
    /* Prepare the command */
    pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_COMMAND_INDATAEXCHANGE;
    pn532_packetbuffer[1] = 1;                   /* Card number */
    pn532_packetbuffer[2] = MIFARE_U_CMD_PWD_AUTH;     /* Xsys MH: Mifare Ultralight Read command = 0x1B */
    memcpy (pn532_packetbuffer + 3, Password, 4);        /* Password Payload 

    /* Send the command */
    if (HAL(writeCommand)(pn532_packetbuffer, 7)) {
        return 0xAA;
    }

    /* Read the response packet */
    HAL(readResponse)(pn532_packetbuffer, sizeof(pn532_packetbuffer));


    memcpy (Response, pn532_packetbuffer, 4);


    // Return OK signal
    return 0xFF;
}
```

And here is how I use the sub-function:

First I checked the card is there, then I read out the configuration pages to check the configuration.

In the 3rd step, I send the PWD_AUTH command with the INDATAEXCHANGE code. If I got the 0xFF for the success, I ran through the process. Which means there was no error in the sending. I got response from the Ntag and from the Pn532.

But I check the response, it is the same thing as the datapayload I sent with the INDATAEXCHANGE code.

### Here is the resault:

```
Hello!
Found chip PN532
Firmware ver. 1.6
Waiting for an ISO14443A Card ...
This will try to read all the data in the Tag
If the Tag is ready, enter any key to start!

Found an ISO14443A card
  UID Length: 7 bytes
  UID Value:  0x4 0xEA 0xFC 0x2 0xD9 0x38 0x80
Seems to be a Mifare Ultralight tag (7 byte UID)

The data for the configuration pages before writing look like this:
 0x4 0x0 0x0 0xFF
 0x0 0x5 0x0 0x0
Send the PWD_AUTH command...
Success code: 0xFF
Response code: 0x40 0x1 0x1B 0xFF
End of the program, enter any key to restart it.
```

I thought I can get the Pack or a Nack, but it seems like to be, that I didn't get anything from the pn532.
How was that happning? And how can I improve the code to get into the Authenticated state?

Thanks for any help.

Main code like here:

```
// choose to SPI or I2C or HSU
#if 0
  #include <SPI.h>
  #include <PN532_SPI.h>
  #include "PN532.h"

  PN532SPI pn532spi(SPI, 10);
  PN532 nfc(pn532spi);
#elif 0
  #include <PN532_HSU.h>
  #include <PN532.h>

  PN532_HSU pn532hsu(Serial1);
  PN532 nfc(pn532hsu);
#else 
  #include <Wire.h>
  #include <PN532_I2C.h>
  #include <PN532.h>

  PN532_I2C pn532i2c(Wire);
  PN532 nfc(pn532i2c);
#endif
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello!");

  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); // halt
  }
  // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
  Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);

  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();

  Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A Card ...");
  Serial.println("This will try to read all the data in the Tag");
  Serial.println("If the Tag is ready, enter any key to start!");
  // Wait for user input before proceeding
  while (!Serial.available());
  while (Serial.available()) Serial.read();
}


void loop() 
{
  int i;                                    // For for-loop
  uint8_t success;                          // Flag to check if there was an error with the PN532
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength;                        // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)
  bool Fail = false;                        
  uint8_t data[4];                         // Array to store block data during reads
  // Keyb on NDEF and Mifare Classic should be the same
  uint8_t Password[4] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };  // using default password
  uint8_t PACK[2] = {0x00, 0x00};
  uint8_t Response[4] = {0,0,0,0};
  // 1. Step: Get the Tag ID

  // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
  // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
  // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidLength);
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (success) 
  {
    // Display some basic information about the card
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Found an ISO14443A card");
    Serial.print("  UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("  UID Value: ");
    for (i=0;i<uidLength;i++)
    {
      Serial.print(" 0x");Serial.print(uid[i],HEX);
    }
    //nfc.PrintHex(uid, uidLength);
    Serial.println("");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Can not read the Tag");
    Fail = true;
  }   

  if (uidLength == 7 && !Fail)
  {
    // We probably have a Mifare Ultralight card ...
    Serial.println("Seems to be a Mifare Ultralight tag (7 byte UID)");
    Serial.println(""); 
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Ooops... Its not a 7-byte Tag");
    Fail = true;
  }   

   // 2. Step: Try to Read and show the Configuration in Page 0x29, 0x2A
   if(!Fail)
   {
     Serial.println("The data for the configuration pages before writing look like this:");
     //for page 0x29
     success = nfc.mifareultralight_ReadPage (0x29, data);
     if (success)
     {
       // Data seems to have been read ... spit it out
       int j;
       for(j=0;j<4;j++)
       {
         Serial.print(" 0x");Serial.print(data[j],HEX);
       }     
       //nfc.PrintHexChar(data, 4);
       Serial.println("");
     }
     else
     {
       Serial.println("Ooops ... unable to read the configuration page 1 !?");
       Fail = true;
     } 
     // for page 0x2A
     success = nfc.mifareultralight_ReadPage (0x2A, data);
     if (success)
     {
       // Data seems to have been read ... spit it out
       int j;
       for(j=0;j<4;j++)
       {
         Serial.print(" 0x");Serial.print(data[j],HEX);
       }     
       //nfc.PrintHexChar(data, 4);
       Serial.println("");  
     }
     else
     {
       Serial.println("Ooops ... unable to read the configuration page 2 !?");
       Fail = true;
     }      
  }      

    // 3. Step: Use PWD_AUTH command to try to get a PAck
  if (!Fail)
  {
      Serial.println("Send the PWD_AUTH command...");
      success = nfc.mifareultralight_IntoAuth(Password, Response);
      // If the success code is 0xFF, we can check the response
      // print success code
      Serial.print("Success code: 0x");Serial.println(success,HEX);
      // print response code
      Serial.print("Response code:");
      int j;
      for(j=0;j<4;j++)
      {
        Serial.print(" 0x");Serial.print(Response[j],HEX);
      }     
      //nfc.PrintHexChar(data, 4);
      Serial.println("");

  }      

  Serial.println("End of the program, enter any key to restart it.");
  // Wait for user input before proceeding
  while (!Serial.available());
  while (Serial.available()) Serial.read();
}
```

Comment: What version of the PN532 library are you using? What's the return value of `HAL(readResponse)(...)`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using the version 1.6 I think. The response I got is something like 0x40 0x1 0x1B 0xFF.... It looks like, that the programm got no response but just give me want I have sent. 0x40 is for the PN532_COMMAND_INDATAEXCHANGE, 0x01 for 1 tag, 0x1B is the PWD_AUTH index, and the 0xFF is the first byte of the default key. So actually I got no feedback from PN532

Comment: That's not really helpful and does not answer my question. You are seeing those bytes as "response" because `pn532_packetbuffer`was not modified by `HAL(readResponse)`. So now it would be interesting why that function fails. So you would need to check the **return value** from the `HAL(readResponse)` call and see if that indicates any specific failure.

Comment: I did another try, please see my update above.

Comment: What you receive as `status` is not the response from the tag but an error code generated by the HAL. It means `PN532_NO_SPACE`, though I don't really understand why you would get that response for the InDataExchange command (unless you modified the size of `pn532_packetbuffer` or the `sizeof()` operator returns a wrong length.

Answer (score 2):

you can't read pack or pwd out of the memory...
8.8.1 section from the ntag Datasheet..

Comment: This is the correct answer; it clearly states in the docs that PASSWORD and PAK return 0x00.

Comment: @craig.tadlock well, the question never asked to READ either password or password acknowledge from the tag. It asked about authentication. And with a successful password authentication you DO get the password acknowledge value from the tag in plain.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you try the following (note that you may need to read a page from the tag after detecting the tag and **before** issuing that authentication command):

```
uint16_t PN532::mifareultralight_IntoAuth (uint8_t *Password, uint8_t *PACK)
{
    /* Prepare the command */
    pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_COMMAND_INCOMMUNICATETHRU;
    pn532_packetbuffer[1] = 0x1B;
    memcpy (pn532_packetbuffer + 2, Password, 4);    /* Password Payload */

    /* Send the command */
    if (HAL(writeCommand)(pn532_packetbuffer, 6)) {
        return 0xAA;
    }
    /* Read the response packet */
    int16_t status = HAL(readResponse)(pn532_packetbuffer, sizeof(pn532_packetbuffer));
    return status;
}
```

If that works, the NTAG PWD_AUTH command might not be supported by the PN532 MIFARE PCD mode.